# If-else conditioning in apache nifi using jolt transformation

Tags: arrays, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

*I have three following JSON input and I want to convert it into expected output by jolt processor in apache NiFi*

---

**input-1**

```json
{
  "array": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "data": {
          "parameter": [
            {
              "key": "water",
              "value": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**input-2**

```json
{
  "array": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "data": {
           "parameter": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**input-3**

```json
{
  "array": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "data": {
          "parameter": [
            {
              "key": "water",
              "value": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
     {
        "id": "4",
        "data": {
          "parameter": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**expected output-1**

```json
{
  "Array": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "properties": [
        {
          "key": "water",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**expected output-2**

```json
{
  "Array": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "properties": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**expected output-3**

```json
{
  "Array": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "properties": [
        {
          "key": "water",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "properties": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**In input-1 parameter is an array and in input 2 parameter is a normal attribute with value equal to empty string.**
**Input-3 is combination of *input-1* and input-2.**

Sometimes parameter comes as an array and sometimes parameter comes as an attribute with value equal to an empty string. So we need to handle this case so that parameter should be converted to properties array always.

**Please help in resolving this issue.**

Answer (score 1):

this spec will help you in resolving your issue :

Note : There's an extra bracket coming inside `"properties" : [ { } ]`, I will check on how to remove it.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "array": {
        "alerts": {
          "*": {
            "data": {
              "parameter": "MANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "array": {
        "alerts": {
          "*": {
            "id": "Array.[&1].id",
            "data": {
              "parameter": {
                "*": {
                  "key": "Array.[&4].properties.[&1].key",
                  "value": "Array.[&4].properties.[&1].value",
                  "": "Array.[&4].properties.[&1].Trash"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "Array": {
        "*": {
          "properties": {
            "*": {
              "Trash": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: So nice, you've handled all three at once !